# Order of the pole of $f(z)=\frac{e^{\sin{z}}-1}{z^3}.$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Let
>
> $$f(z)=\frac{e^{\sin{z}}-1}{z^3}.$$
>
> a) Determine if $f$ has a pole at $0$ and determine its order.
>
> b) If $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n$ denote a Laurent serie of
>   $f$ valid in the region $0<|z|<2,$ determine the coefficients
>   $a_{-3},a_{-2},a_{-1}$ and $a_0.$

For a), it seems easy. the multiplicity is 3, thus the order of the pole should be 3. But the answer is 2. How come?

For b), I know the individual taylor series for the functions $\sin{z}$ and $e^{z}$. But I need their respective Laurent series in order to combine them. I'm not sure how I should approach this part.

Comment: what do you mean by + holomorphic?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(z)=e^{\sin z}$. Then:

- $f(0)=1$;
- $f'(0)=1$;
- $f''(0)=1$;
- $f'''(0)=0$,

you have$$\frac{e^{\sin z}-1}{z^3}=\frac{1+z+\frac{z^2}2+\cdots-1}{z^3}=z^{-2}+\frac{z^{-1}}2+(\text{terms of order greater than $0$)}.$$

Comment: So the order of the pole is the number of terms of order greater than $0$?

Comment: No. If $f$ has a pole at $a$, the order of the pole is the largest $n$ such that, near $a$, $f(z)$ can be written as$$f(z)=\frac{a_{-n}}{(z-a)^n}+\frac{a_{-(n-1)}}{(z-a)^{n-1}}+\cdots$$

Comment: So if this is the case, then I have no $a_{-3}$ in order to solve $b)$ So $a_{-3}=0$?

Comment: Yes. And also the fact that $a_{-2}\neq0$.

Comment: How would your solution differ if we instead had $\sin(1/z)$?

Comment: It would change **a lot**. There is no simple expression (that I know of) for the Lauren seies of $\exp\left(\sin\left(\frac1z\right)\right)$.

Comment: The reason I asked that question is because I assume you cant just differentiate like you've done above? Why not? Is it because in order to do what you have done (Use Taylor series in place of Laurent), the function needs to be holomorphic in all of $\mathbb{C}?$

Comment: I can't differentiate it at $0$ because $\exp\left(\sin\left(\frac1z\right)\right)$ isn't even *defined* at $0$.

Comment: What I don't understand is, why you used Taylor series and not Laurent series. I see that in this case Taylor = Laurent, but why?

Comment: In another thread I asked how to compute an integral using series expantion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969634/evaluate-int-z-1-frac-sin1-zz-22dz/2970859?noredirect=1#comment6135173_2970859 However, in order to do that I need to expand the integrand but I can't do it using your method in this thread.

Comment: Since $0$ is not a singularity of $e^{\sin z}$, I computed its Taylor series about $0$ and then I divided what I got by $z^3$. This gave me a Laurent series.

Answer (score 1):

(a) Near $z = 0$, $\sin z \approx z$, so $e^{\sin z} \approx 1 + z$, so $\frac{e^{\sin z} - 1}{z^3} \approx \frac{1}{z^2}$.

(b) The Taylor series of $e^{\sin z}$ up to order $3$ will give you the corresponding Laurent series for $f$. ($e^z$ and $\sin z$ are entire functions, so their "Laurent series" are just Taylor series). Approximating $e^z = 1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^3}{6}$ and $\sin z = z - \frac{z^3}{6}$ is enough.

Comment: Why does "entire" implicate Taylor = Laurent?  Why does order $3$ suffice?

Comment: Should have said "will give you the corresponding Laurent series for $f$ up to order $0$." And Laurent series defined on a disk around the origin with negative-order terms have singularities at the origin (basically by definition) and so aren't entire.