# Evaluate $\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{\sin{1/z}}{(z-2)^2}dz.$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

This is a question from an old exam. The two integrals are seemingly similar, but the first one seems quite tedious compared to the other one. It seems, according to the prof solution, that the hard part in the first integral is computing the residue at $z=0.$

> Evaluate the intergals
>
> a) $$\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{\sin{(1/z)}}{(z-2)^2} \ dz$$
>
> b) $$\int\limits_{|z|=3}\frac{\sin{(1/z)}}{(z-2)^2} \ dz$$

In the first, we have $2$ poles, first one is $z_1=0$ and the second one is a pole of order $2$, which is $z_2=2.$ However, only $z_1$ is inside our unitcircle so we only need to compute $\text{Res}_{z_1}(f(z))$ and apply the residue theorem.

Since our function is of the form $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{(z-z_1)^k}$ the residue is given by

$$\text{Res}_{z_1}(f(z))=\frac{g^{k-1}(z_1)}{(k-1)!},$$

and here $k=2$ and $(\sin(1/z))'=-\cos(1/z)/z^2$, so

$$\text{Res}_{z_1}(f(z))=-\frac{\cos\frac{1}{z_1}}{z_1^2}=...\text{this is the moment I realised I'm screwed.}$$

Howver, computing the residue at $z_2=2$ for the other integral I can use conventional methods, but not here.

Can someone break down the main difference between these integrals and show how to find the residue at $z_1=0?$

**EDIT:**

I need to solve $a)$ using Laurent series.

Comment: You have an essential singularity at $z_1=0$, so you should write down a Laurent series representation instead.

Comment: How can you immediately tell the singularity is of essential nature?

Comment: Because of the behavior of $\sin(1/z)$ at $z=0$. If you try to visualize it for just $z$ on $\mathbb{R}$ you can immediately see it is not continuous and not a pole. Since $\sin(1/z)$ is holomorphic everywhere else in a neighborhood of $0$, it is an essential singularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re **$(a)$ and series**, [given](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Series_definition)
$$\sin{z}=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\frac{z^7}{7!}+\frac{z^9}{9!}+...=
\sum\limits_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}z^{2k+1} \tag{1}$$
we have
$$\sin{\frac{1}{z}}=\sum\limits_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\frac{1}{z^{2k+1}}$$
then
$$\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{\sin{(1/z)}}{(z-2)^2} dz=\sum\limits_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z^{2k+1}(z-2)^2}dz \tag{2}$$

Using [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula):

$$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz \tag{3}$$
where $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-2)^2}$, because $2$ is outside $|z|=1$, we have
$$f^{2k}(0)=\frac{(2k)!}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z^{2k+1}(z-2)^2}dz$$
then $(2)$ becomes
$$\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{\sin{(1/z)}}{(z-2)^2} dz=2\pi i\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}\frac{f^{2k}(0)}{(2k)!}\right) \tag{4}$$
But
$$f^{'}(z)=-\frac{2}{(z-2)^3}$$
$$f^{''}(z)=\frac{2\cdot3}{(z-2)^4}$$
$$f^{'''}(z)=-\frac{2\cdot3\cdot4}{(z-2)^5}$$
$$f^{(4)}(z)=\frac{2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5}{(z-2)^6}$$
$$...$$
$$f^{(2k)}(z)=\frac{(2k+1)!}{(z-2)^{2k+2}} \tag{5}$$
and $(4)$ becomes
$$\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{\sin{(1/z)}}{(z-2)^2} dz=
2\pi i\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\frac{1}{(-2)^{2k+2}}\right)=
2\pi i \frac{1}{4}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\frac{1}{2^{2k}}\right) \tag{6}$$
but
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\frac{1}{2^{2k}}=\cos{\frac{1}{2}}$$
from [cosine series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Series_definitions), thus
$$\int\limits_{|z|=1}\frac{\sin{(1/z)}}{(z-2)^2} dz=
 \frac{\pi i}{2} \cos{\frac{1}{2}} \tag{7}$$

Comment: I don't think many people realise how helpful full solutions like these are sometimes, especially with nice explanations for each step. Thanks a lot. However, I have a question regarding the part "because 2 is outside $|z|=1$ we have". How would it be different if $2$ was inside of the intended contour of integration? Furthermore, how can you, in the sum just replace $f^{2k}(0)$ with $f^{2k}(z)$ like that? Doesnt the latter give the sum different values for $k=0,1,...$?

Comment: @Parseval re "How would it be different if $2$ was inside of the intended contour of integration?" - in this case I wouldn't be able to use Cauchy's integral formula, because $f(z)$ wouldn't be holomorphic inside the contour, as required by the theorem.

Comment: Re "Furthermore, how can you, in the sum just replace $f^{(2k)}(0)$ with $f^{(2k)}(z)$ like that? Doesn't the latter give the sum different values for $k=0,1,...$? " - It's vice-versa, I used $f^{(2k)}(z)$ to calculate $f^{(2k)}(0)$, in order to find each term of the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

We substitute $w = 1/z$ and taking the explicit parametrization $z=e^{it}$ we see that the integration path changes the orientation, this brings a minus in front of the integral, so 
we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J_1 
&= 
\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\sin(1/z)}{(z-2)^2} \; dz
\\
&=
-\int_{|w|=1}\frac{\sin w}{\left(\frac 1w-2\right)^2} \; \left(-\frac 1{w^2}\right)\;dw
\\
&=
\int_{|w|=1}\frac{\sin w}{(1-2w)^2} \; \;dw
\\
&=2\pi\; i
\operatorname{Residue}_{w=1/2}
\frac{\sin w}{(1-2w)^2}
\\
&=2\pi\; i
\cdot\frac 14\operatorname{Residue}_{w=1/2}
\frac
{\sin\left( \left(w-\frac 12\right)+\frac 12\right)}
{\left(w-\frac 12\right)^2}
\\
&=2\pi\; i\cdot\frac 14\cdot\cos\frac 12
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
because in the expansion $\sin\left( \left(w-\frac 12\right)+\frac 12\right)
=
\sin\left(w-\frac 12\right)\cos\frac 12+
\cos\left(w-\frac 12\right)\sin\frac 12
$
only the $\sin\left(w-\frac 12\right)$ brings the needed odd power that contributes to the residue.

Let us check the above numerically, pari/gp:

```
? intnum( t=0, 2*Pi, sin( exp(-I*t) )  / ( exp(I*t)-2)^2 * I * exp(I*t) )

%1 = 2.2522481052807061131814259376142973690 E-58
   + 1.3785034646766524887891155026097526287*I
? Pi/2*cos(1/2.)
%2 = 1.3785034646766524887891155021962680546
```

(Result was manually rearranged.)

The other integral is converted by the same trick into one over $|w|=1/3$, and the contour avoids the pole $1/2$.

Comment: I need a more general method, that works for the majority of integrals of this kind, that is Taylor/Laurent expansions. But this is indeed a nice solution. Sorry I did not specify what I needed. Edited my post now.

Answer (score -1):

The integrand has a third-order zero at infinity, therefore the residue at infinity is $0$. Assuming that the contour goes around the origin counterclockwise, the first integral is $-2 \pi i$ times the residue at $z = 2$ and the second integral is $0$.

Comment: The answer of the first one is $2\pi i\text{Res}_{z=0}(f)$ and not residue at $z=2$ since $z=2$ is outside of $|z|=1.$  However the residue att $z=2$ is the negative of the residue at $z=0$ so the answer for that is zero.

Comment: So you're saying that $\operatorname{Res}_{z = 2} = -\operatorname{Res}_{z = 0}$, $\operatorname{Res}_{z = 0}$ is the answer for a), and $-\operatorname{Res}_{z = 2}$ is not the answer for a)?

Comment: Ah...somehow my eyes missed the minus sign there. But why calculating the residue at $z=2$ at all on a) since it's outside the unit circle?

Comment: Because the calculation is trivial. You have a regular function $f$ times $(z - 2)^{-2}$, the residue is $f'(2)$.