# Solving a complex integral $\oint_L\frac{e^{1/(z-a)}}zdz$ using Cauchy's formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I am practicing complex integration using Cauchy's formula, and I ran into a problem. The following integral:

$$\oint_{L}{\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z-a}}}{z}}dz$$ where $$L=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=r\}$$ for some $r\neq|a|$.

So the contour is a circle in the origin that can not pass through one of the singularities $a$. The other singularity being $0$. That means it's eather of a greater or lesser radius than $|a|$. If it is of a radius lesser than $|a|$, then by Cauchy's formula:
$$\oint_{L}{\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z-a}}}{(z-0)}}dz = \frac{2\pi i}{e^{1/a}}$$
If, however, $r>|a|$ then the integral would be the sum of the integrals of two separate disjunct contours containing only the $0$ singularity and only the $a$ singularity. This is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to solve the integral of the contour containing the $a$ singularity (can't get it in Cauchy formula form).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

I would suggest to use [Residue theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) here. This theorem is a consequence of Cauchy’s formula.

For a radius $r > \vert a \vert$, you get

$$\oint_{L}{\frac{e^{\frac{1}{z-a}}}{z}}dz =2i\pi \left(\frac{1}{e^{1/a}}+\mbox{Res}(f,a)\right)$$

Comment: Yes, I tried to, but I'm not sure how to get $Res(f,a)$ to be equal $\frac{1}{a}$.

Comment: I edited because I may have done an error in The computation of the residue. You can compute it by finding $a_{-1}$ where $\sum_{-\infty}^\infty a_n (z-a)^n$ is Laurent expansion of $f$ at $a$.

Comment: I see. I'm struggling with that too a bit, but from what I've done so far, I don't think the series is going to have any negative terms ?

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2970859). Instead of taking the residue at $z = a$, take the residue at $z = \infty$, which is the value of $-e^{1/(z - a)}$ at $z = \infty$.

Comment: This is the better approach.